# How to use raw_input function of python2.7 to write strings s and integer values in cells of an existing travel order.xlsx file?

Tags: python-2.7, openpyxl, xlrd, xlsxwriter

Below is a code I have copied from here and I want to ask what should I use to load  an existing excel file (.xlsx) and write data to various cells of a named worksheet of that excel file (.xlsx) and save the data to a different filename?

```
import Tkinter as tk
import xlwt
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
from xlwt.Utils import cell_to_rowcol2

class MyForm(tk.Frame):
def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, cnf, **kw)

    self.fname = tk.StringVar(value="travelorder.xlsx")
    self.sheet = tk.StringVar(value="DOMESTIC")
    self.cell  = tk.StringVar(value="c4")
    self.value = tk.StringVar(value="1234")

    tk.Label(master, text="File").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    tk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.fname).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=4, 
    pady=4)

    tk.Label(master, text="Sheet").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    tk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.sheet).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=4, 
    pady=4)

    tk.Label(master, text="Cell").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    tk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.cell).grid(row=2, column=1, padx=4, 
    pady=4)

    tk.Label(master, text="Value").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
    tk.Entry(master, textvariable=self.value).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=4, 
    pady=4)

    go = tk.Button(master, text="Do it!", 
    command=self.write_to_xls).grid(row=4, column=1, padx=4, pady=4, 
    sticky=tk.W)
    self.grid()

    def write_to_xls(self):
       # create new workbook
       xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook('travelorder.xlsx')

    # add sheet using given name
    ws= xfile.get_sheet_by_name(self.sheet.get())
    # ws = wb.add_sheet(self.sheet.get())
    # get offset of cell to write to
    row,col = cell_to_rowcol2(self.cell.get())

    # write text to cell
    ws.write(row, col, self.value.get())

    # save to given file name
    xfileout=raw_input('Enterfilename to save:')
    xfile.save(xfileout)

def main():
master = tk.Tk()
myform = MyForm(master)
tk.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

I want to put up a GUI in which the user will input data, which will be written to specific cells in a specific worksheet in an already existing .xlsx file.

Please help..

Lee

Comment: from where?  There is no link on here.

Comment: why are you both creating a GUI and using raw_input?

Comment: Hi I asked the wrong question, sorry. The question is this: how can I save the user entry data from the GUI to a different sheet of an existing .xlsx file? The existing file is travelorder.xlsx and the GUI data entry should be saved in a different sheet of that mentioned existing file.